# Arduinocloud Begin without WiFiConnectionHandler Parameter

Tags: arduino, iot, arduino-esp8266, arduino-esp32

I searched in documentation and google a little but didn't see the "**arduinocloud.begin**" function call without the "**WiFiConnectionHandler**" parameter. I am handling wifi connections with the **ESP8266WiFiMulti** library and don't want to change it.

Is there a way to bypass the parameter of begin and other events connected to it?